# If Array Values Match Another Array's Values, Then

Tags: php, functions, user-meta, array

I have a user drop-down field that includes High, Medium, or Low ranking. Each ranking has three requirements for evaluation types. I also have three additional drop-downs with options to choose between those requirements, but they must meet the requirements in any order. I want to alert the user if they do not. Again, they do not need to be in the same order as the requirements.

```
// Get requirements from Ranker field
if ($user->$currentRanking == 'High'){
    $rankShouldBe1 = 'Standard Evaluation';
    $rankShouldBe2 = 'Business Review & Coaching';
    $rankShouldBe3 = 'Coaching Session Only';
} elseif ($user->$currentRanking == 'Medium'){
    $rankShouldBe1 = 'Standard Evaluation';
    $rankShouldBe2 = 'Reduced Evaluation & Coaching';
    $rankShouldBe3 = 'Coaching Session Only';
} elseif ($user->$currentRanking == 'Low'){
    $rankShouldBe1 = 'Standard Evaluation';
    $rankShouldBe2 = 'Standard Evaluation';
    $rankShouldBe3 = 'Reduced Evaluation & Coaching';
} else {
    $rankShouldBe1 = '-';
    $rankShouldBe2 = '-';
    $rankShouldBe3 = '-';
}

// These are the two arrays I want to check if they match
$evaltypesReq = array(
    $rankShouldBe1,
    $rankShouldBe2,
    $rankShouldBe3,
);
$evaltypesSch = array(
    $user->pbe_evaltype_month1, // Option Field 1
    $user->pbe_evaltype_month2, // Option Field 2
    $user->pbe_evaltype_month3, // Option Field 3
);

// I have tried the following three methods with the If/Then statement below (obviously not at the same time):
$containsAllValues = array_intersect($evaltypesReq, $evaltypesSch) == $evaltypesReq;
$containsAllValues = 0 == count(array_diff($evaltypesReq, $evaltypesSch));
$containsAllValues = !array_diff($evaltypesReq, $evaltypesSch);

if ($containsAllValues == true){
    $results .=  'Everything looks great!';
} elseif ($containsAllValues == false){
    $results .=  'This is not allowed.';
} elseif ($containsAllValues == ''){
    $results .=  'Please select the evaluation types you have scheduled.';
} else {
    $results .=  '';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s one way to solve this:

- sort both arrays
- loop through them and compare them item by item (they should be equal, because arrays are sorted)

.

```
sort( $evaltypesReq );
sort( $evaltypesSch );
$containsAllValues = true;
foreach ( $evaltypesReq as $k => $v ) {
    if ( $evaltypesSch[$k] !== $v ) $containsAllValues = false;
}
```